# Push Notification using FCM in-between web and App

Tags: c#, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging, xcode8

I have tried to implement push Notification in-between from C#.Net(MVC) Web to React Native (Android and IPhone). No Error showing in my code but not show notification in App.

I have tried as reference gave in Stack overflow already

```
try
  {
 string server_api_key =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SERVER_API_KEY"];
 string sender_id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SENDER_ID"];
 WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
 tRequest.Method = "post";
 tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
 tRequest.Headers.Add($"Authorization: key={server_api_key}");
 tRequest.Headers.Add($"Sender: id={sender_id}");
 var data = new
 {
 to = "AAAAaQ5neZA:................................XXXX",
 priority = "high",
 data = new
 {
   message = response,
   name = loginUser.EmployeeName,
   userId = uId,
   status = true
   }
 };
  var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
  Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

  tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
  Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
  dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);               

  WebResponse tresponse = tRequest.GetResponse();
  dataStream = tresponse.GetResponseStream();
  StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
  string sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

  tReader.Close();
  dataStream.Close();
  tresponse.Close();
  return sResponseFromServer;
}
catch (Exception)
   {
     throw;
   }
```

Comment: Is there anything useful in the server response?

Comment: return the response from server. if not return also their is no action in app